# Getting response from unix commands executed via PHP

Tags: php, unix, cron, exec, passthru

I would like to list the Cron tasks for a given user in the browser. I am using the following, which works fine via SSH:

> crontab -u username -l

Which outputs something like:

```
*/2 * * * * cd /home/username/public_html/cron; php -q -c ./ cron_4.php
*/2 * * * * cd /home/username/public_html/cron; php -q -c ./ cron_3.php
*/2 * * * * cd /home/username/public_html/cron; php -q -c ./ cron_2.php
0 0 * * * cd /home/username/public_html/cron; php -q -c ./ cron_1.php
```

However, when I try to do it via PHP...

```
$return = array();
$command = "crontab -u username -l";
passthru($command, $return);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($return);
echo "</pre>";
```

I only get...

```
int(1)
```

Whereas I was expecting an array containing each of the above lines.

How can I achieve the expected result via PHP?

Comment: [Read the docs](http://php.net/passthru). the 2nd arg on passthru() is the exit value of whatever you were running externally. You probably want [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead.

Comment: @MarcB is "exit value" synonymous with "return status"? I did read the docs and I have tried `exec()`, but exec only return the last line whereas I need all of them, however when I use exec instead of passthru I get `array(0) {}`

Comment: You could also try <a href="http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php">backtick</a>

Comment: yes, return status, exit status. they're all the same. e.g. if were doing a passthru() on  a simple C program that simply does `printf('foo'); exit(42);`, then your $return would have been 42, not $foo. `'foo'` would be output, not a return value.

Comment: I mean, I understand it now, but I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up  using `exec()`

```
$r=[];
exec($command,$r);
```

The actual problem was something to do with permissions and is irrelevant to the question as I stated it.